# What does adultery mean in the 7th commandment?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashas-yisro, aseres-hadibros, arayot

Exodus 20:14, the 7th 'commandment' of the Decalogue.

Does it mean only having sex with someone else' wife or having sex outside marriage?

What is the actual Hebrew word and what possible interpretations could there be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Hebrew word here is *ne'ifa*, and it doesn't occur all that often. The standard interpretation means "intercourse between a married woman and a man not her husband." The Talmud observes that just like commandment #6, #7 can warrant the death penalty in theory.

The word is not *zonah*, which means "stray." That word can either mean prostitution, or a married woman straying from her husband. (When Leviticus prohibits a Kohen from marrying a Zonah, the Talmud says that means a married woman has who cheated with anyone -- even though she's now widowed.) "Don't do *zanah*" would be directed at a woman only. "Don't do *ne'ifa*" applies to men and women.

Commentaries such as Sforno (cited above) suggest that the Ten Commandments also signify categories that encompass the entirety of the commandments; thus, the specific commandment was "don't do *ne'ifa*", but the philosophical category from that illustration is  intended to cover all prohibited sexual relations.

While there's this illustrative-category thing, the direct meaning of the seventh commandment is most definitely **not** prohibiting sex out of marriage. *That* prohibition would be either [Deuteronomy 23:18](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=5&CHAPTER=23#C4259), according to some; or of post-Biblical nature according to others. (See link for more.)

Comment: So either deuteronomy or post biblical nature. I thought all mitzvah are in the torah (according to some answers here). So we should cross out post biblical/post torah part right?

Comment: @J.Chang No not all mitzvos are in the Torah. There's mitzvos d'rabbonon, like Purim, Chanukah, etc. Nu?

Answer (score 16):

The word is *sin'af*, תִנְאָף. *Rashi* and *Rosh* say it refers to sexual relations with a married woman not one's wife. *Chizkuni* says it refers to any prohibited sexual relations, and, if I understand him correctly, ibn Ezra says the same. *S'forno* says it refers primarily to the former but also to the latter. (All these sources are in their commentaries on this verse.)

Comment: So, sinaf or neifa? Which one is right?

Comment: @JimThio different conjugations of the same verb. "Sin'af" means "you will do *ne'ifa*" (preceded by a "DON'T")

Comment: According to the Talmud (Niddah 13b) the verse also proscribes male masturbation.
תנא דבי רבי ישמעאל "לא תנאף", לא תהא בך ניאוף בין ביד בין ברגל
Rashi (ibid.)
ביד - מוציא זרע לבטלה
[See also Bach (EH 23, s.v Assur)].